# A Typescript variable that is available both statically and dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a readonly value that I want to access either statically or dynamically. I could write it this way:

```
class Example {
   static readonly FOO = 1;
   readonly FOO = 1;
}
```

The result would be:

```
const example = Example();
example.FOO === Example.FOO;
```

This approach seems very clumsy. Is there a way I can write this in one line?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why isn't it enough to have it statically? What can you gain by having the same thing on the instance as well? Besides being redundant it's error prone

Comment: ^ agreed. You always access the properties dynamically. The static modifier changes where the variable is stored, specifically it is stored on the class constructor. See http://aliolicode.com/2016/05/07/typescript-static-members/

Comment: In some frameworks (Angular, for example), all variables passed to a template are set dynamically. In other words, `<p>{{User.name}}</p>` requires `public User = new User()` in the component. What if I do not want to instantiate the class?

Comment: right in that case that's an angular specific problem which afaik there is no solution e.g similar issue with enums https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, templates cannot access objects that are not exposed by a component. see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2885.

Something like this is required:

```
class Controller {
    public example = Example;
    ...
}
```